# om.google.firebase.sessions.SessionLifecycleService crash on Firebase Bom Update to 32.7.1

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

after update to firebase bom 32.7.1 and has higher trend of crashes because of this our Application crash rate has increased i am providing you further details related to the crash
Android Devices :
Q Mobile - FIH Foxconn
Q Mobile - View Max Pro
Q Mobile - View Max

after update to ***firebase bom 32.7.1*** and has higher trend of crashes because of this our Application crash rate has increased i am providing you further details related to the crash
Android Devices :
Q Mobile - FIH Foxconn
Q Mobile - View Max Pro
Q Mobile - View Max

Devices OS :
Android 10

Devices OS :
Android 10

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.